# How to insert an Object into DB

Tags: sqlite

Hi
   Iam new to android.i know insertion of strings into SQlite DB,But i want to insert an Object into DataBase.Please tell me the way.

Answer (score 2):

you have to map the object into tables and columns or serialize it into a blob.

relational databases don't know anything about objects.  it's called 'object-relational impedence mismatch'.